# Erro de PHP, "Call to undefined function"

Tags: php

Olá, sou novo no PHP e estou tendo o seguinte erro:

> Call to undefined function RealizarLogin()

O que pode ser ?

Código para chamar a função:

```
if(isset($_POST["btn-logar"]))
{
   include_once('../Controller/Login/Logar.php');

   RealizarLogin();
}
```

Codigo da Função:

```
class Logar{

    var $usuario;
    var $senha;

    function RealizarLogin($usuario, $senha)
    {
        $this->$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        $this->$senha = $_POST['senha'];

        $login = $conn->prepare('SELECT count(1) as qtd FROM login WHERE usuario=:usuario AND senha=:senha');
        $login->bindParam(':usuario',$usuario);
        $login->bindParam(':senha',$senha);
        $login->execute();
        $retorno = $login->fetchAll();


        if($retorno[0]['qtd'] > 0)
        {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
            $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;

            print "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0;URL=../View/System/Home.php'>";
        } else {

            print "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0;URL=../View/Error/Error1.php'>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: A função não existe ou o nome foi digitado  errado.

Comment: O nome está correto, mas acho que estou errando na hora de chamar a função.

Comment: adicione o código na pergunta senão é impossível responder

Comment: Coloca o arquivo que a função está também, esta usando linux?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma função é diferente de um método, ele não pode ser invocada sem a referência(objeto/classe), para resolver isso crie o objeto primeiro e depois chame o método.

Seu arquivo principal deve ficar:

```
if(isset($_POST["btn-logar"]))
{
   include_once('../Controller/Login/Logar.php');
   $login = new Logar();
   $login->RealizarLogin();
}
```

A palavra chave `var` era utilizada no php4(legado) para definir propriedades uma classe, do php5 para frente utilize os modificadores de acesso, public, protected e private.

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Resolveu meu problema.